# Multiple linear regression in Matlab R2014a

Tags: matlab

Is there any function that does this? I keep searching and the closest match is **regression**, but it's for the simple linear regression. In Matlab R2015a they have implemented **regress**, but I don't have that version.

Thanks.

Comment: `fitlm`. Multiple linear regression and simple regression use the same function, it just depends on the dimensions of your inputs

Comment: Also `\` does a form of multiple linear regression.

Comment: Thanks, I found out what was happening :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `fitlm` and `regress` do the same thing.